# Deploy Windows Azure Cloud Services to multiple data centers?

Tags: azure, cloud

What is the recommended way of deploying a single Windows Azure Cloud Services application to multiple data centers?

Should I put an existing app on hold in all data centers, then after deployment is complete re-enable them? Or there is a better way doing this?

Ideally I'd like to have an ability to set in a Windows Azure cloud project's config file the list of data centers so that during a single publish operation the app would be uploaded to multiple data centers simultaneously (for example North Central US, West Europe and East Asia data centers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described will require a bit of custom deployment logic. I would recommend that you get familiar with PowerShell and the [Windows Azure Management Cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841). A bunch of examples for how to deploy packaged with PowerShell are available on [Github](https://github.com/search?q=azure%20cmdlets&ref=commandbar).

I would upload your Azure package and service configuration files to each host service's staging slot that you have in each datacenter (i.e. your multiple datacenters) using the same PowerShell script with different arguments for each hosted service. You'll need to have some custom wait logic that polls the status of the staging slot deployment and waits for the READY status. Once this is complete you know your VM is ready and if your application load quickly you can then perform a VIP Swap using PowerShell as well.

The PowerShell commands that you will need to accomplish this are the following:

- **New-Deployment** (Use this to deploy to each of your datacenter's hosted services)
- **Get-HostedService** (Use this to get the status of your newly deployed hosted services)
- **Move-Deployment** (Use this to perform a VIP Swap once all your staging slot deployments are ready)

Note that even when you build this there is a chance that things will be out of sync for a few seconds at best and a few minutes at worst so your new deployment will always need to be backwards with your underlying data storage systems/schema.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the [Windows Azure Service Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799) for this.  PowerShell tends to be repetitive and slow for multiple deployments (i.e. the package is uploaded to storage for each deployment, even if it is the same package).  There is a great and complete example on using the REST API at [Windows Azure ServiceManagement Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c).  We have extended this sample for a similar situation:  We have 45+ microsites using the same code base and use the REST API to deploy to each service instance asynchronously.  We upload the package to an Azure Blob and then trigger an asynchronous update of each service using the Blob URL. With the REST API, you can run your updates from a build server or an Azure Worker Role.